# Double digit subscript not appearing properly

Tags: align

I generated the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1Income_i + \beta_2Limit_i + \beta_3Rating_i 
+\beta_4Cards_i + \beta_5Age_i + \beta_6Education_i \end{split}\\ 
\begin{split}\beta_7Gender_i  
+ \beta_8Student_i + \beta_9Married_i + \beta_10Ethnicity_i + \epsilon_i 
\end{split}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Which is producing the following output

[image]

How do I correct the code so that the last beta (B10) appears correctly? Thanks

Comment: the syntax is `_{9}`, `_{10}`  etc omiting the braces sometimes works, but don't do it:-)

Comment: also use `\mathrm{Rating}` and similarly the other words, as your image shows, math italic is designed to make adjacent letters look like a product of variables and not like a word. Also do not use `split` if you have no alignment points (`&`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
Y_{i} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}\mathrm{Income}_{i} + \beta_{2}\mathrm{Limit}_{i} + \beta_{3}\mathrm{Rating}_{i} 
+\beta_{4}\mathrm{Cards}_{i} + \beta_{5}\mathrm{Age}_{i} + \beta_{6}\mathrm{Education}_{i} +\\ 
\beta_{7}\mathrm{Gender}_{i}  
+ \beta_{8}\mathrm{Student}_{i} + \beta_{9}\mathrm{Married}_{i} + \beta_{10}\mathrm{Ethnicity}_{i} + \epsilon_{i} 
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

The syntax for subscripts is `_{9}`, `_{10}` etc omiting the braces sometimes works, but don't do it:-)

As you have no alignment points `align` and `split` are not suitable (also you seemed to be missing one `+`?) I used `multline` here but it is still slightly too wide, I left it as perhaps your real page size is different, or you could have a third line in the `multline`.